# Is splitting an array into 2 subarrays and solving them recursively still O(log(n))?

Tags: algorithm, runtime, time-complexity

I found this algorithm that calculates the median of 2 sorted lists on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/median-of-two-sorted-arrays/.
It says, it's O(log(n)).
But is this really the case?

What I'm confused about:
These lines split an array into 2 subarrays (with Python's slicing) and solve them recursively:

```
if n % 2 == 0: 
   return getMedian(arr1[:int(n / 2) + 1], 
      arr2[int(n / 2) - 1:], int(n / 2) + 1) 
else: 
   return getMedian(arr1[:int(n / 2) + 1],  
      arr2[int(n / 2):], int(n / 2) + 1)
```

But splitting the array looks like O(n) for me.
So in my opinion, the whole algorithm must be O(n * log n)...

Here, you can see the whole code of the algorithm I'm talking about:

```
# using divide and conquer we divide 
# the 2 arrays accordingly recursively 
# till we get two elements in each  
# array, hence then we calculate median 

#condition len(arr1)=len(arr2)=n 
def getMedian(arr1, arr2, n):  

    # there is no element in any array 
    if n == 0:  
        return -1

    # 1 element in each => median of  
    # sorted arr made of two arrays will     
    elif n == 1:  
        # be sum of both elements by 2 
        return (arr1[0]+arr2[1])/2

    # Eg. [1,4] , [6,10] => [1, 4, 6, 10] 
    # median = (6+4)/2     
    elif n == 2:  
        # which implies median = (max(arr1[0], 
        # arr2[0])+min(arr1[1],arr2[1]))/2 
        return (max(arr1[0], arr2[0]) + 
                min(arr1[1], arr2[1])) / 2

    else: 
        #calculating medians      
        m1 = median(arr1, n) 
        m2 = median(arr2, n) 

        # then the elements at median  
        # position must be between the  
        # greater median and the first  
        # element of respective array and  
        # between the other median and  
        # the last element in its respective array. 
        if m1 > m2: 

            if n % 2 == 0: 
                return getMedian(arr1[:int(n / 2) + 1], 
                        arr2[int(n / 2) - 1:], int(n / 2) + 1) 
            else: 
                return getMedian(arr1[:int(n / 2) + 1],  
                        arr2[int(n / 2):], int(n / 2) + 1) 

        else: 
            if n % 2 == 0: 
                return getMedian(arr1[int(n / 2 - 1):], 
                        arr2[:int(n / 2 + 1)], int(n / 2) + 1) 
            else: 
                return getMedian(arr1[int(n / 2):],  
                        arr2[0:int(n / 2) + 1], int(n / 2) + 1) 

 # function to find median of array 
def median(arr, n): 
    if n % 2 == 0: 
        return (arr[int(n / 2)] +
                arr[int(n / 2) - 1]) / 2
    else: 
        return arr[int(n/2)] 


# Driver code 
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 6] 
arr2 = [4, 6, 8, 10] 
n = len(arr1) 
print(int(getMedian(arr1,arr2,n))) 

# This code is contributed by 
# baby_gog9800
```

Comment: In Python if you slice a list, you make a copy, and hence that will take *O(n)*. The slicing in the GFG article does not create copies, it simply holds pointers how the list is sliced.

Comment: It splits two arrays into halfs, so from 2n size you go to n/2+n/2=n so you halved the problem. Though if it was just one array of size n then doing n/2+n/2=n would still be O(n).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.  Many candidates have got bad marks in programming interviews for missing this.

Slicing a list in python makes a copy.

Copying half the list takes *O(n)* time.

And this algorithm takes *O(n)* time all together (you should have a go at figuring out why it's not *O(n log n)*)

You really need to know how your language works to figure this out for any particular example, because some languages provide ways to slice a list without copying elements.  In java you can call `list.sublist(start,end)`, for example, to get a slice without copying.

Comment: In Java's case, it's the library, not the language. The contract of the interface method `List.sublist()` is that it returns a *view* of the original list, valid in the absence of structural changes performed other than through the view. That makes O(1) implementations feasible and likely, as in java.util.ArrayList -- but not guaranteed.

Comment: Ok. In each call of getMedian, we call getMedian exactly one time (if n >= 2). So I can argue via Master Theorem that f(n) = f(n/2) + Θ(n). (1/2)^1 < 1. Because of that, we got Θ(n) all together?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are confusing the *implementation* for the *algorithm*. This Python *implementation* is `O(n)` because of the linear time slicing operations it performs, but the *algorithm* itself is `O(log(n))` since it doesn't actually need to perform the linear time operation of copying the elements in the slice -- it can operate on the same list without needing to create a new one. This makes `f(n) = O(1)` in the master theorem, making the overall runtime of the algorithm `O(log n)`. You could choose to implement the algorithm in Python in a manner that does not require slicing (similar to the C++ and Java implementations on GeeksForGeeks, for instance) which would run in `O(log n)` time.

The distinction between algorithms and their implementations is why algorithmic analyses are performed on pseudocode, and not implementations in actual programming languages. Implementation details like this one often serve as a source for confusion. Algorithms thus tend to be explicit about the operations used and their time complexities (like indexing, slicing and so on) based on their requirements.

Comment: So instead of slicing, I do just omit the whole array all the time and 2 more parameters like `l` and `r` (for left and right) that tell me which interval I'm handling in that recursion call?

Comment: @Alpha That's right! Doing that will make the Python implementation `O(log n)` as well.

Comment: The *algorithm* implemented in this python code is O(n).  Similar code in a different language might implement an O(log n) algorithm.

Comment: @MattTimmermans You're confusing the _implementation_ for the algorithm too :) To re-emphasize your statement, The algorithm *implemented* in this python code is O(n). Algorithms are unambiguous -- among other things, they do not "change" their time complexity. In this case, the inherent algorithm is `O(log n)` and will always remain `O(log n)`. The given Python implementation, however, runs in `O(n)` time. Similar code in a different language will implement the _same_ algorithm because the manner in which the code solves the problem (the _algorithm_) stays the same.

Comment: No, you're confusing the algorithm the author implemented for the one he should have implemented.